# Refreshing data connections - 'error' handling

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA which opens an Excel file, refreshes all data connection's tables, saves the file and closes it. Simple enough.

The command to refresh all data connections is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

However, on rare occasions there may be an issue with the network connection, which causes Excel to prompt me for an alternative connection:

[image]

At this point, code execution is halted, waiting for a connection. Often, I just have to hit OK and if the network issue has subsided, connection is restored and code execution continues.

**But I would like this to be able to run without any intervention, even if there is a temporary network 'blip'.** I can't seem to find a way to trap this 'error'.

Does anyone have any idea how I might prevent this pop up halting execution and instead throw an error or allow me to capture the fact?

Comment: No idea about how to catch the error. Wondering if using the alternative connection as primary one raises the same error, but because I cannot reproduce the problem this is a shot in the darkness. Anyways, upvoted

Comment: The issue is that there is no alternative connection. It just asks me for one in case there is. Basically I need to suppress that pop up somehow so execution continues.

Comment: Doesn't prevent the popup - trying to close it after it appears ... and hopefully, someone will come up with something far, far better than this 'last resort' (clearly not tested) ... /cont

Comment: ... Before `RefreshAll`, spin up a 2nd hidden Excel instance; with it, load a Workbook you have saved somewhere known that contains VBA that loops monitoring the active window (using Windows API calls) and if that window is your target then navigate through its children to find and programmatically click the 'OK' button; loop in 2nd Workbook keeps going until first Workbook passes a message (ie when refresh is complete) to 2nd Workbook to stop and close; likely include timeout for loop in 2nd Workbook just in case

Comment: Maybe you could try iterating connections one at a time, get the connection string from the object, try connecting with ADODB, if it is successful refresh the connection. It won't refresh broken connections, but sounds like you don't need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this solution is as-per my comments on 4th Aug. It includes code for a 'monitor' Workbook (the Workbook that is dynamically opened to watch for, and close, the "SQL Server Login" dialog) and code to be added to your existing 'master' Workbook (ie the Workbook that calls `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`).

There are a few things to note:

1. I assume the "SQL Server Login" dialog becomes the foreground window when it appears.
2. In creating this code, I actually haven't been able to make an "SQL Server Login" dialog appear so the code in the 'monitor' Workbook that identifies the relevant window for this dialog, then gets the 'OK' button on it, then clicks that button, may need tweaking with the aid of Spy++, or similar.
3. Further to point 2, the code below includes test code (in the 'master' Workbook) to show a Msgbox and test code (in the 'monitor' Workbook) to find that MsgBox window, get it's "OK" button and click it ... this code is to 'prove the concept' and can be deleted.
4. The Log procedure in the 'monitor' Workbook is for test / diagnostic purposes, this can be retained or deleted as you see fit.
5. The code in the 'monitor' Workbook needs to be able to run so, e.g., it should be saved in a trusted location.
6. All code is documented to clarify its purpose, but happy to provide further clarity if required.

So first the 'monitor' Workbook. This Workbook should be named 'monitor.xlsm' (or adjust `sPathToMonitor` in the master Workbook to match whatever you want to call it) and should be saved in the same folder as your 'master' Workbook.

In a standard Module named 'WinAPI', add:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
            (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
            (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
            (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
            (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#End If

Const mlMAX_LEN As Long = 255


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get a handle to the foreground window
' Returns (LongPtr/Long): The handle
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Function GetForegroundWin() As LongPtr
#Else
Function GetForegroundWin() As Long
#End If
    GetForegroundWin = GetForegroundWindow
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the window caption for the given window handle
' Parameter hWnd (LongPtr/Long): The window handle
' Returns (String): The caption name
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Function GetWindowCaption(hWnd As LongPtr) As String
#Else
Function GetWindowCaption(hWnd As Long) As String
#End If
    Dim lLen As Long
    GetWindowCaption = String$(mlMAX_LEN, Chr$(0))
    lLen = GetWindowText(hWnd, GetWindowCaption, mlMAX_LEN)
    GetWindowCaption = Left$(GetWindowCaption, lLen)
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the window class name for the given window handle
' Parameter hWnd (LongPtr/Long): The window handle
' Returns (String): The class name
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Function GetWindowClassName(hWnd As LongPtr) As String
#Else
Function GetWindowClassName(hWnd As Long) As String
#End If
    Dim lLen As Long
    GetWindowClassName = String$(mlMAX_LEN, Chr$(0))
    lLen = GetClassName(hWnd, GetWindowClassName, mlMAX_LEN)
    GetWindowClassName = Left$(GetWindowClassName, lLen)
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get a child window of the given parent Window with the matching class name and / or caption
' Parameter hWndParent (LongPtr/Long): The handle to the parent Window
' Parameter sClassName (String): The class name of the child window ... if omitted then sCaption must be provided
' Parameter sCaption (String): The caption of the child window ... if omitted then sClassName must be provided
' Returns (LongPtr): The handled to the child window, or 0 if it could not be identified
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Function GetChildWindow(hWndParent As LongPtr, Optional sClassName As String = vbNullString, _
        Optional sCaption As String = vbNullString) As LongPtr
    Dim hWndChild As LongPtr
#Else
Function GetChildWindow(hWndParent As Long, Optional sClassName As String = vbNullString, _
        Optional sCaption As String = vbNullString) As Long
    Dim hWndChild As Long
#End If
    If hWndParent = 0 Then Exit Function
    Do While True
        hWndChild = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, hWndChild, vbNullString, vbNullString)
        If hWndChild = 0 Then Exit Function
        If (sClassName = GetWindowClassName(hWndChild) Or sClassName = vbNullString) And _
                (sCaption = GetWindowCaption(hWndChild) Or sCaption = vbNullString) Then
            GetChildWindow = hWndChild
            Exit Function
        End If
        GetChildWindow hWndChild, sClassName, sCaption
    Loop
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Click the button
' Parameter hBtn (LongPtr/Long): The handle to the button to click
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Sub ButtonClick(hBtn As LongPtr)
#Else
Sub ButtonClick(hBtn As Long)
#End If
    Const BM_CLICK As Long = &HF5
    SendMessage hBtn, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
End Sub
```

Then in the 'ThisWorkbook' Module, add:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    WaitForDialog
End Sub


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Wait for the "SQL Server Login" dialog to appear ... if it does, close it ... stop waiting after a timeout
' or an 'exit file' is created
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub WaitForDialog()
    Dim dtTimeOut As Date
    dtTimeOut = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30) ' adjust timeout for your needs
    
    Dim sPathToExitFile As String
    sPathToExitFile = Environ$("temp") & "\exit_now.txt" ' must use same path in calling 'master' Workbook
    
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hWin As LongPtr, hBtn As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hWin As Long, hBtn As Long
    #End If
    
    Log oFSO, "Starting"
    
    Do While True
        
        ' get foreground window ... is it the dialog we are interested in ... if so, get first child with caption "OK"
        ' ... assuming it is a button, then click it
        hWin = WinAPI.GetForegroundWin
        If hWin <> 0 Then
            If StrComp(WinAPI.GetWindowCaption(hWin), "SQL Server Login", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                hBtn = WinAPI.GetChildWindow(hWin, "", "OK")
                If hBtn <> 0 Then
                    WinAPI.ButtonClick hBtn
                    Log oFSO, "Clicked the ""OK"" button"
                    ' if the dialog is only ever seen once, the code can now exit the Do/Loop ... otherwise, keep looping
                Else
                    Log oFSO, "Found the dialog, could not find the ""OK"" button"
                End If
            End If
            
            ' TEST CODE ... TO BE DELETED ... DISMISSES THE TEST MSGBOX SHOWN BY THE MASTER WORKBOOK
            If StrComp(WinAPI.GetWindowCaption(hWin), "Unique title", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                hBtn = WinAPI.GetChildWindow(hWin, "", "OK")
                If hBtn <> 0 Then
                    WinAPI.ButtonClick hBtn
                    Log oFSO, "Clicked the ""OK"" button in the MsgBox"
                    ' if the dialog is only ever seen once, the code can now exit the Do/Loop ... otherwise, keep looping
                Else
                    Log oFSO, "Found the MsgBox, could not find the ""OK"" button"
                End If
            End If
            
        End If
        
        ' chill for a bit
        Dim sglChillUntil As Single
        sglChillUntil = Timer + 2
        Do While Timer < sglChillUntil Or Timer < 1 ' <1 if new day
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        ' found the 'exit file'? ... if so, exit
        If oFSO.FileExists(sPathToExitFile) Then
            oFSO.DeleteFile sPathToExitFile, True
            Log oFSO, """Exit file"" found ... exiting"
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        ' timeout? ... if so, exit
        If Now > dtTimeOut Then
            Log oFSO, "Timeout ... exiting"
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        Log oFSO, "... waiting ..."
    Loop
    
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.Quit
End Sub


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Log what's happening to a file
' Parameter oFSO (Object): The FSO Object
' Parameter sText (String): The text to log
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Log(oFSO As Object, sText As String)
    Dim sPathToLogFile As String
    sPathToLogFile = Environ$("temp") & "\waitfordialog_log.txt"
    With oFSO
        ' 8 = IOMode.ForAppending; True = create new file if not exist; -1 = TristateTrue (UTF-16)
        With .OpenTextFile(sPathToLogFile, 8, True, -1)
            .WriteLine Time & ": " & sText
            .Close
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Save and close the 'monitor' Workbook.

Next, additions to the 'master' Workbook. Doesn't matter what the name of this Workbook is, but it must be saved in the same folder as the 'monitor' Workbook, or adjust `sPathToMonitor` accordingly.

In the procedure that calls `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`, before `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`, add:

```
Dim sPathToExitFile As String
sPathToExitFile = Environ$("temp") & "\exit_now.txt" ' must use same path in 'monitor' Workbook

Dim sPathToMonitor As String
sPathToMonitor = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\monitor.xlsm" ' or wherever you have saved the 'monitor' Workbook

Dim sPathToVbsFile As String
sPathToVbsFile = Environ$("temp") & "\vbs_file.vbs"

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    ' in case the 'exit file' didn't get deleted by the 'monitor' Workbook or it exited before the queries
    ' completed refereshing the previous time we ran
    .DeleteFile sPathToExitFile, True
    ' start with a fresh VBS file just in case the path to the 'monitor' Workbook has changed
    .DeleteFile sPathToVbsFile, True
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' open the 'monitor' Workbook using a VBScript so that it does not block this code from executing
    ' 2 = IOMode.ForWriting; True = create new file if not exist; 0 = TristateFalse (ASCII)
    With .OpenTextFile(sPathToVbsFile, 2, True, 0)
        .Write "CreateObject(""Excel.Application"").Workbooks.Open(""" & sPathToMonitor & """)"
        .Close
    End With
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run sPathToVbsFile, , False ' False = do not wait
```

... then after `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`, add:

```
    ' TEST CODE ... TO BE DELETED ... SIMULATE WAITING
    Dim dtTimeOut As Date
    dtTimeOut = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
    Do While Now < dtTimeOut
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ' TEST CODE ... TO BE DELETED ... SHOWS A TEST MSGBOX THAT WILL BE DISMISSED BY THE MONITOR WORKBOOK
    MsgBox "Testing", vbOKOnly, "Unique title"
    
    ' wait
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
    
    ' we're done ... create the 'exit file' to inform the 'monitor' Workbook it can exit
    .CreateTextFile(sPathToExitFile).Close
End With
```

Comment: Fantastic stuff John. Sadly I can't easily test it but will deploy this to my solution and experiment. Your great commentary should make it easy to tweak as I need. Thanks again. Well deserved.

Comment: Thx, please comment at me if need any other clarification etc!